# Can i install ubuntu 18.04 on this specs Dell 3521 core i5 ram 8 hd 1 terabyte amd 2 gb ?!

Tags: ubuntu-core

I need to install ubuntu on my dell 3521 core i5 
Ram 8 gb 
Hd 1 terabyte 
Vga amd 2 gb 
Windows 7 ultimate
Can it working fine or should i get an older version

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop system requirements are:**

> - 64-bit 2GHz dual core processor or better (32-bit not supported anymore, other flavours will continue supporting 32-bit system)
> - 2GB RAM
> - 25GB of disk space
> - Graphics processor and display capable of at least 1024x768
> - A DVD drive or a USB port for the installation media
> - Internet access is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You will be fine. I'm running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 with 8GB and a 2.13 GHz processor. With a small SSD the performance for most desktop work is just fine. Build times are okay. Runs cool.  Try it out as a LiveCD first. Performance will be dreadful but it will give you more confidence.